# DataGrid Column's Element Style in CodeBehind has no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am setting column's Element style in code behind using MultiConverter. Even though the converter is being accessed and there's no error at all, cell's background is not getting updated.

```
private void DgBinding(DataTable dt)
{            
    string prevCol = "";

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (dc.ColumnName.StartsWith("Delta"))
        {
            prevCol = dc.ColumnName;
            continue;
        }
        DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = dc.ColumnName,
            Binding = new Binding(dc.ColumnName)
        };

        this.dgTarget.Columns.Add(col);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prevCol) && prevCol.StartsWith("Delta"))
        {
            MultiBinding m = new MultiBinding {Converter = new TimeSeriesColorConverter()};

            m.Bindings.Add(new Binding(dc.ColumnName));
            m.Bindings.Add(new Binding(prevCol));

            Style style = new Style();
            style.TargetType = typeof(TextBlock);

            Setter setter = new Setter
            {
                Property = BackgroundProperty,
                Value = m
            };

            style.Setters.Add(setter);

            col.ElementStyle = style;
        }
        prevCol = dc.ColumnName;
    }
}
```

If I just use, `col.CellStyle` it works and the background's are getting updated, but with `ElementStyle` there's no effect at all. Any idea why?

**I can't use XAML as the data is dynamic timeseries and # of Columns are unknown.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `TargetType` as `TextBlock` but when setting the property inside setter you are referring to DataGridCell's `BackgroundProperty`. When elemesntstyle looks for TextBlock changes, it finds nothing and no change occurs.

As for CellStyle, Setter works because of the same reason.

Change your code to this :

```
         Setter setter = new Setter
            {
                Property = TextBlock.BackgroundProperty,
                Value = m
            };
```